# R concatenate row labels with colnames

Tags: r, paste

```
a<-as.factor(c('a','a','b','b','c','d'))
b<-as.factor(c('a','b','c','c','d','a'))
c<-as.factor(c('a','b','d','d','c','b'))
x<-data.frame(a,b,c)

  a b c
1 a a a
2 a b b
3 b c d
4 b c d
5 c d c
6 d a b
```

I have a very large data table (using datatable package) and I would like to simply
take the column names and append them to the row factor values for easy identification.

So in the above simple example (using a data frame for illustration) I would have something
like

```
a    b   c
a:a  b:a c:a
a:a  b:b c:b
a:b  b:c c:d
..
..
a:d  b:a c:b
```

I had tried (unsuccessfully) to do some type of apply and paste combination.
But I can't quite pass the colname arguments to paste to each column correctly.
Any ideas on how I could accomplish this task for large data tables? A datatable
approach would be great, but dataframe is fine as well, since it's only a one time
action.

Comment: May I ask why on Earth would you want to do such an operation??? You'd need to drag those useless prefixes with your whole huge data frame making it twice larger. If it is for presentation purposes, add those at the very end when printing result. There is no way it would be useful for any processing...

Comment: I have a large data mining operation that ends splitting then operating on all of the column attributes and further splitting results into small lists. I want to be able to take the hundreds of lists and rbind, then rank-sort them, but the colnames information will be lost. If I pre-process this way, I can keep track of them on the final aggregated result.

Comment: @sashkello The prefixes will only have a negligible impact on the data frame size. R stores factors as numeric indices into a set of levels, not as actual character strings.

Comment: Ah, OK, they are factors, sorry, misread it. It's quite reasonable in such case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data frame solution:

```
x[] <- mapply(function(n, f) {
    levels(f) <- paste(n, levels(f), sep=":")
    f
}, names(x), x)
```